# Alguien me podria explicar como solucionar este problema de clases en javascript?

Tags: javascript, clase

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito hacer este método para un examen y he tratado de todas las maneras pero la verdad no se como puedo hacerlo, no me pasa el test básicamente tengo que agregar un objeto con un nombre y edad que me lo pasan como parámetro al array amigos y todo esto dentro de una clase

Comment: pues this.amigos.push({nombre:nombre, edad.edad});

Comment: Muchas gracias lo habia puesto al reves!!!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.